# How to bind the "SelectedValue" property of a combobox that gets his elements from a datasource?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, combobox

I think I almost figured it out, but I have a bug: the binding through the DataSource property makes the first element from the bound datasource the default value of the combo, but this is bad for me because this default value will be propagated to the first row of the datasource that is bound through the "SelectedValue" property and it overwrites the correct value with a bad value. How to solve this?

Here is my code: (In the northwind database I want to be able to select from a combo an employee that will be inserted in an Order)

```
this.comboBox1.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedValue", this.ordersBindingSource, "EmployeeID", true));
this.comboBox1.DataSource = this.employeesBindingSource;
this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = "FullName";
this.comboBox1.ValueMember = "EmployeeID";
```

Answer (score 0):

i do this :

```
DataRow dr=this.ordersBindingSource.Current;
  Combo.Text="";
  if(dr!=null)
  {
    if(dr[Combo.ValueMember]!=DBNull.Value)
    {
     Combo.SelectedValue=dr[Combo.ValueMember].ToString();        
     Combo.Text=dr[Combo.DisplayMember].ToString();         
    }
  }
```

do this in recordChange