# When binding both the Items and SelectedValue to aListBox I seem to get a race condition, how to fix?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, .net-2.0, strongly-typed-dataset

For a legacy project, I have a WinForm with a BindingSource1 bound to a strongly typed SQL 2005 DataSet. There is a BindingSource2 bound to the first on a relation.

When selecting a Row in DataGridView, I'd like to present a ListBox with all the child rows with one Item selected based on a value in the selected Row. I bound the DataGridView to BindingSource1, the ListBox' Datasource is BindingSource2, ValueMember and DisplayMember are set to the primary key and a description respectively. I added a Databinding of SelectedValue to the foreign key in BindingSource2.

On Load of the Winform and when the selected row changes by changing the sort order, everything is fine, all related rows show up in the ListBox and the correct item is highlighted.

When I click into the DataGridView, .Net seems to change the SelectedValue of the ListBox and repopulate its items after that. In Effect, when the newly selected item is already in the ListBox it gets highlighted, then the ListBox is filled with the new items and the first one is selected (SelectedValue is reset).

Is there any .EndEdit, .CancelSomething or .UpdateFoo that I am missing? How to ensure the internal sequence of Items.Clear(), (fill), and SelectedValue = x? I am stripping down the problem to a minimal project but if anyone has an idea I'd like to skip that part ; )

Added: All Bindings are set using the Designer of Visual Studio 2008 Pro, the project is VB.Net Framework 2.0 Winform.

Comment: I suggest you put anything loading up in a Post Back function. If it is not that simple look at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319927

Comment: Thanks @indofraiser but I am not changing the DataSource so I am sure this is not what breaks the Bindings. I merely select another row and need to fill the list with other child rows. Also, Post Back functions are ASP only, aren't they?

Answer (score 0):

I am documenting my workaround to further describe the problem I have. It might help others and possibly lead to a real solution.

Like in "[How to bind the "SelectedValue" property of a combobox that gets his elements from a datasource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124081/how-to-bind-the-selectedvalue-property-of-a-combobox-that-gets-his-elements-fr?rq=1)" the control is filled by DataSource, DisplayMember and ValueMember plus has a DataBinding of its SelectedValue. There seems to be a problem: In ListBox and ComboBox the Position of the DataSource (BindingSource2 in my example) define the current selected Item, binding SelectedValue to another DataSource leads to erratic behaviour.

For my workaoround I bound ListBox.DataSource to a DataView wich is filled / filtered in BindingSource2_ListChanged so the DataSource of the ListBox has no Position to use as SelectedItem / Index / Value. It then uses the DataBinding only and my UI shows the expected Behaviour.